# Woocommerce filter products by custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to wordpress and woocommerce. I have created custom taxonomy 'city' for product.
Now on my website I want to filter the products by this custom taxonomy. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin might help.  I haven't tested it but in the video it looks like it can filter by multiple taxonomies.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-meta-data-filter-and-taxonomy-filter/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone, I did something similar by adding action to woocommerce_product_query, of course you probably want to use $_GET variables for taxonomy and terms:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product') {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'producer',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('company1, company2'),
                'operator'=> 'IN',
                'include_children'=> true,
            )
        );

        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $tax_query;
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'][] = $tax_query;
    }


    return $query;
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on a site just now too, partially using this to help. so putting this here in case it helps others with multiple custom taxonomies.

```
 // Apply custom taxonomies filter to product query
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'apply_custom_taxonomy_filters');
    
    function apply_custom_taxonomy_filters($query)
    {
        if (!is_main_query() || !$query->is_post_type_archive('product')) {
            return;
        }
    
        if (isset($_GET['wine_search']) && $_GET['wine_search'] === 'true') {
            // Initialize tax_query array
            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    
            if (isset($_GET['origin']) && $_GET['origin'] !== '') {
                $query->set('tax_query', array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'origin',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $_GET['origin'],
                    ),
                ));
            }
    
            if (isset($_GET['varietal']) && $_GET['varietal'] !== '') {
                $query->set('tax_query', array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'varietal',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $_GET['varietal'],
                    ),
                ));
            }
    
            $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
        }
    
        return $query;
    }
```

This relies on having a button w/ id #wine-search and adds the click event to the url parameters. for my purposes the url gets messy but for now I have a functioning search using multiple taxonomy choices. was after